# How to test which factors are responsible for a change in a variable over time?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, survey, demography

I have survey data from two waves: one in 2019, one in 2020. There is a large change in one of the survey answers, and I would like to test which respondent characteristics are responsible for that change. For example, is it that the views of women have changed a lot? Or the views of Asian Americans? The views of neurotic people? The survey is ran with different people each year, so I don't think I can just run a create a new variable of "change in views" and then run a regression with that new variable as the dependent variable.

Obviously I can look at graphs, but I would like to be able to run a statistical significance test here if possible.